# deploy windows form application with database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, setup-deployment

I'm trying to deploy windows form application with database and install it on client computer. I've used visual studio 2013 and its (localdb)\v11.0 and entity framework code first . I've build setup with prerequisite .NET framework 4.5 , sql express 2008 r2 and windows installer 4.5 . after installation on client computer and running the app I got this error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\codFirst.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

connection string

```
<add name="dbConnection" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=codFirst;AttachDbFilename=|datadirectory|\codFirst.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

the app is pretty simple and it's just for test but does not work on client computer .

please help me to handle this .

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the database to run locally on that machine (and each machine it might be installed to)?  Each database would be isolated from the others?

Comment: @AdamPlocher yes . exactly.

Comment: By the looks of it in your appdomain the `DataDirectory` is not set. If this isn't a webapp, make sure you call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase);` assuming your codFirst.mdf is in the same folder as your exe (which is a bit of bad practice but that is another topic)

Comment: After installation, did you check if the mdf file is being copied at proper location? What value is set to `datadirectory`? Are you setting it anywhere in the code? You might want to log that value in log file to be able to check if that is using right path.

Comment: @rene no this is windows app . I'm trying to connect application to sql express 2008 on client computer

Comment: Can you try without having "\" in your .mdf file name ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the .mdf file has been copied in the installation folder. if you have idea for connection string I'll become happy to hear that.

Comment: @Subbu yes but the result is the same

Comment: if that is a windows app then for sure there is no DataDirectory set. So in which folder is your codFirst.mdf file after deployment and where is your exe? Full paths please, [edit] your question with that info.

Comment: @rene both are in the same location c:\program files\setup\ ...

Comment: Just a quick check, can you put the full path in the connectionstring `AttachDbFilename=c:\program files\setup\codFirst.mdf` and then try again. If that doesn't work either move that codFirst.mdf to c:\temp and adapt the path accordingly and re-test. Let us know what works. What are the related errors btw?

Comment: @rene I tried both way but does not work